# Store output of shell command in sqlite

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, sqlite

If I execute a certain shell command in node js, the output is on the console. Is there a way I can save it in a variable so it can be POST to Sqlite database.

```
const shell = require('shelljs');
  shell.exec('arp -a');
```

In this scenario, I want to store the IP address of a specific MAC/Physical address into the database. How can this be done?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the output of the command you're passing to `exec`. To do that, just call stdout, like this:

```
const shell = require('shelljs');
const stdout = shell.exec('arp -a').stdout;
```

Then just parse that output to get your ipaddress:

```
const entries = stdout.split('\r\n'); 

 // entries sample
    [ '',
      'Interface: 10.17.60.53 --- 0xd',
      '  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type',
      '  10.11.10.52           6c-4b-90-1d-97-b8     dynamic   ',
      '  10.10.11.254          xx-yy-53-2e-98-44     dynamic   ']
```

Then you can filter your wanted address with some more manipulation.

**EDIT**:

To get the ip address, you could do:

```
let ipAddr = null;

for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
   if (entries[i].indexOf('6c-4b-90-1d-97-b8') > -1) {
      ipAddr = entries[i].match(/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/)[0];
      break;
   }
}

console.log(ipAddr); // '10.11.10.52'
```

Comment: +1. And if you don't want the output in the console, you need to pass {`silent`: true} option in the `exec` function

Answer (score 2):

I'm merely copy pasting [from the docs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs#execcommand--options--callback). You should research more.

You need to add a listener to `stdout`

```
var child = exec('arp -a', {async:true});
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  /* ... do something with data ... */
});
```

Or adding the callback directly when calling `exec`

```
exec('some_long_running_process', function(code, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('Exit code:', code);
  console.log('Program output:', stdout);
  console.log('Program stderr:', stderr);
});
```

Comment: I would accept this answer, as it is always a good idea to use async mode when working with databases. Plus, it points out an obvious lack of self research.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the result of the command run using `shell.exec` with the `.output` property. Try the code below.

```
var shell = require('shelljs');
var result = shell.exec('arp -a').output;
```

If you don't want the result in the console, you can specify the `silent` option.

```
var result = shell.exec('arp -a', {silent: true}).output;
```

Now, you can use regular expressions to extract ip and mac address from the `result`.

I am getting the result of the command like below:

```
? (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [ether] on eth0
? (yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy) at yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy [ether] on eth0
```

You can use the following code to extract ip and mac.

```
var res = result.split("\n").map(function(item){
  return item.match(/\((\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\) at (..:..:..:..:..:..)/);
});
console.log(res[0][1]); //IP of first interface
console.log(res[0][2]); //MAC of first interface

console.log(res[1][1]); //IP of second interface
console.log(res[1][2]); //MAC of second interface
```

**NOTE**

- I was not able to find the `.output` property in the documentation but trying the `shell.exec` function in the node console revealed it.
- The `.stdout` property or the `exec` function mentioned in other answers doesn't work for me. They are giving `undefined` errors.